# Rails - Making where query faster on 1 million records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where-clause

I have a table called books_groups which has 1 Million records. In Rails, I am simply trying to do a where query

```
BookGroup.where(group_id: 291)
```

which is taking 1642 ms.

I have also added indices on this table

```
CREATE TABLE `books_groups` (
`book_id` int NOT NULL,
`group_id` int NOT NULL,
 KEY `index_books_groups_on_book_id` (`book_id`),
KEY `index_books_groups_on_group_id` (`group_id`)
```

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

How can I make it faster?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Postgres, MySQL? Can you print the query planning of that query?

Comment: @SebastianPalma given the reference to "InnoDB" I think we are looking at MySQL or MariaDB

Comment: @SebastianPalma yes its MySQL

Comment: Since this appears to be a join table the answer for most of your other queries is most like to add a compound index on book_id AND group_id. Not sure why you're querying it directly anyways?